# Why am I getting "no boot disk has been detected" after installing Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, system-installation, uefi, secure-boot

After installing a Linux distro (Fedora 19, to be exact) on a Windows 8 machine I got the message:

> No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the problem was that I had tried to install a 32 bit version of Linux. When installing on an x86 system with [Secure Boot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot) ([UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)) a 64 bit version of Linux is needed.